# Cast function doesn't work well with sum function

Tags: r

I recently encountered a problem when I try to use cast function to summarize some variables by groups.

The details is the following:

dataframe

```
id  time    variable    value
1   1   x1  5
1   2   x1  3
2   1   x1  6
2   2   x1  2
1   1   x2  6
1   2   x2  5
2   1   x2  1
2   2   x2  4
```

The following code works very well:

```
subjmeans <- cast(mdata, id~variable, mean)

subjmeans

id  x1  x2
1   4   5.5
2   4   2.5
```

But when I replace the mean function (built in the cast function) with "sum", i.e. cast(mdata, id~variable, sum)

R reports the following error message:

> ```
> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 0
> ```

I also tried other functions like "max","length", everything works except for "sum".

This is super weird, especially given that the same code worked very well with "sum" last week.

Best
Xinghua

Comment: can you change it to `reshape2::dcast` instead of `cast`

Comment: I can't reprooduce the behavior with your example `\reshape::cast(mdata, id ~ variable, sum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine

```
reshape::cast(mdata, id ~ variable, sum) 
#   id x1 x2
#1  1  8 11
#2  2  8  5
```

Only possible explanation is the masking of function `sum` by the same function name from other packages loaded

#### data

```
mdata <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), time = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), variable = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2"), value = c(5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: My friend tried on his computer. Everything works well. But after uninstalled and re-installed R, I still have the same problem. What is wrong? Any idea?

Comment: @XinghuaWang As I mentioned, it is not reproducible for me.  Can you try `reshape2::dcast(mdata, id ~ variable, sum)`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried reshape2::dcast(mdata, id ~ variable, sum). R says "Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : no function as".fun". Any idea?

Comment: The problem is solved. I let R forget everything by entering rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE)). Thanks for your help, guys.